# Missing program but which one?

Tags: windows-10

I am running Windows 10 and keep getting the following error dialog intermittently as I work.

[image]

How can I find out what is triggering this as it is getting very annoying to have to close these dialogs down.

Comment: Your .exe file association is incorrect.  You should reset it.  There are existing questions here at Superuser that explain how to do that and numerous tutorials that exist.  As for which program attempting to launch the Windows Explorer executable that is not possible to determine from the information you provided.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the response but it's not that. The file associate for .exe is fine. I have no issues in running .exe files